# I am designing a very large banner. I have a simple question

Tags: adobe-photoshop, billboard

Sorry for such a lame question but, when I blow up my image to 350 inches wide in photoshop and zoom in to 100%, the picture looks blurry, but as I zoom out it looks perfect. Would the same effect happen if we hung this image from the rafters of a stadium, in other words does the blurry picture become clearer from further away? I am sure is does but, dont want to screw this up.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, things will look clearer from further away. See the question AndrewH linked. It's a balance between resolution/viewing distance.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to talk with the vendor who is printing the banner to determine the appropriate DPI (dots per inch) of their output. While pixelated images will look better from a distance, it may still not be desirable. You are working with a very large image, however, if your output size is 350 inches. Most large-format work I've done runs anywhere from 100-150dpi.